# Grain/Grunge Gradient In illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Does anybody have an idea how to get this kind of unsmooth grainy gradient effect in illustrator ?

[image]

I tried with sketch torn edges, i tried with a grunged up photo, edited the levels and saved that as a bitmap, then applied it to a mask, but i does not look good

[image]

So does anybody know a better way to get this effect in Adobe Illustrator ?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way in Illustrator is to use a color to transparent gradient fill. Then use `Effect > Pixelate > Pointillize` on that gradient fill.

[image]

Adjusting the `Cell Size` of the effect will result in more or less speckle clumps. And altering the span of the gradient can control how much drop off there may be.

This effect *will* be an embedded raster image with a clipping mask when saved or exported to flat file formats such as EPS. However, the ppi of the effect will automatically adjust according to `Effects > Document Raster Effects Settings` within Illustrator if the effect is kept "live".

There are **several** effects which will achieve similar, but different, results... you'll have to experiment to find the one you're specifically looking for....

[image]

Comment: This looks very promising, ill be thoroughly testing this technique, thanks Scott !