# How to do this grungy effect in adobe illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, minimalistic

i wanted to ask if anyone knows how to do the daily minimal effect in adobe illustrator. I already played around with pathfinder to do the grungy effect but im still missing something. It kinda looks like it is sketched on paper.

This is a picture for reference:
[image]

And this is what i get from playing around:
[image]

It would be awesome if anyone knows the answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you searched this site? What have you tried?

Comment: That grunge effect looks like it's just a low quality image. It doesn't look like an effect to me. At least I can't tell from this image size.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62184/grain-grunge-gradient-in-illustrator

Answer (score 1):

Change the Document raste effects to 72dpi.

Use the Pointilize effect with a value of 3.

Duplicate it and change its mode to multiply, rotate it a little and edit the effect to 4.

Dupplicate this new circle, rotate it again and edit the effect to 6.

Repeat this step if you need.

Image below:

[image]